# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Headers wildcard being ignored?

Tags: http, browser, cors

I am having trouble getting a cross domain CORS request to work correctly using Chrome.

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 30 Oct 2012 20:04:28 GMT
Server:BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.3
```

Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load domain. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

And the python code serving the options request is:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
self.send_header('Content-Length', '0')
self.end_headers()
```

It seems the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` wildcard is being ignored?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Support for wildcards in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header was [added to the living standard](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/251) only in May 2016, so it may not be supported by all browsers. On browser which don't implement this yet, it must be an exact match: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header

If you expect a large number of headers, you can read in the value of the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header and echo that value back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.

Comment: resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers")); // allow any headers

Comment: On ruby, "if request.headers['Access-Control-Request-Headers'] then
     headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = request.headers['Access-Control-Request-Headers']
 end" looks ok for me.

Comment: This might help you *(it shows a set of Apache .htaccess for Access-Control-Expose-Headers but you can copy&paste to set it for Access-Control-Allow-Headers as well)* : [Right… So, Access-Control-Expose-Headers Does Not Support Wildcard…- iCompile Blog](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/right-so-access-control-expose-headers-does-not-support-wildcard/)

Comment: I've got an Apache config for this, useful when serving static content: http://serverfault.com/a/799764/129921

Comment: @monsur: [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/799791/129921) pointed out that wildcards are allowed now, at least in theory, so I updated your answer to reflect this. If you don't like my style, feel free to edit to your taste.

Comment: A word of warning, you may run into trouble by relying on passing back the Access-Control-Request-Headers value if you also allow the browser to cache the preflight response (with Access-Control-Max-Age). You don't know that the first request lists all the headers of consecutive requests.

Comment: I don't want to be a buzzkill here, but doing this in production is certainly a security concern.

Comment: @monokrome would be great if you can tell us how this would be a security concern in production..

Comment: @prettyvoid the basic question is how much data is allowed to be put inside of the header? could you have a 2GB header? That would show your server down. Receiving and echoing arbitrary data could be a problem. Maybe not.

Answer (score 60):

Those CORS headers do not support `*` as value, the only way is to replace `*` with this:

`Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With`

---

### `.htaccess` Example (CORS Included):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Connection
  Header unset Time-Zone
  Header unset Keep-Alive
  Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Headers
  Header unset Access-Control-Expose-Headers
  Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Methods
  Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

  Header set   Connection                         keep-alive
  Header set   Time-Zone                          "Asia/Jerusalem"
  Header set   Keep-Alive                         timeout=100,max=500
  Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Origin        "*"
  Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Headers       "Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With"
  Header set   Access-Control-Expose-Headers      "Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With"
  Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Methods       "CONNECT, DEBUG, DELETE, DONE, GET, HEAD, HTTP, HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, OPTIONS, ORIGIN, ORIGINS, PATCH, POST, PUT, QUIC, REST, SESSION, SHOULD, SPDY, TRACE, TRACK"
  Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials   "true"

  Header set DNT "0"
  Header set Accept-Ranges "bytes"
  Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
  Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  Header set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

---

#### F.A.Q:

- Why `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` values are super long?

  Those do not support the `*` syntax, so I've collected the most common (and exotic) headers from around the web, in various formats [#1](https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/253ea42ede4225c4f359#file-all_http_headers__separated_by_newline-txt) [#2](https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/9a1f6b523562320c0a37#file-all_http_headers__json-json) [#3](https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/67e065eb80a7a79ed356#file-all_http_headers__separated_by_comma-txt) <sub>(and I will update the list from time to time)</sub>
- Why do you use `Header unset ______` syntax?

  GoDaddy servers (which my website is hosted on..) have a weird bug where if the headers are already set, the previous value will join the existing one.. (instead of replacing it) this way I "pre-clean" existing values <sub>(really just a a *quick && dirty* solution)</sub>
- Is it safe for me to use 'as-is'?

  Well.. mostly the answer would be **YES** since the `.htaccess` is limiting the headers to the scripts (PHP, HTML, ...) and resources (.JPG, .JS, .CSS) served from the following "folder"-location. You optionally might want to remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` lines. <sub>Also `Connection`, `Time-Zone`, `Keep-Alive` and `DNT`, `Accept-Ranges`, `Vary`, `X-UA-Compatible`, `X-Frame-Options`, `X-Content-Type-Options` and `X-Xss-Protection` are just a suggestion I'm using for my online-service.. feel free to remove those too...</sub>

*<sub>taken from my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored#comment48526275_13147554)</sub>*

Comment: This definitely saved my life. I was using a CDN provider, with CORS enabled, and also i was allowing it in my website with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin        "*"` but nothing worked until i used this. Not even the CDN provider had an answer for us. I run the website in **Siteground**, perhaps, as **GoDaddy**, it is mandatory to unset first everything.

Comment: In my specific case, I had to remove from `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` all these methods: HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2

Comment: Is HTTP/2 even a valid 'Method' ? Does upgrading from HTTP/1.1 to 2 work like that or something ? If I look here: https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-does-http-2-work/ the HTTP/... part is supposed to go as the third place, not the first, where the Method is placed.

Comment: Maybe to support HTTP/2.0 you need to add the 'PRI' method ?

Comment: btw, I noticed that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` is not allowed by Safari

Comment: ASP.NET and SignalR users need to add `x-signalr-user-agent` to the list.

Answer (score 17):

I found that `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` should be set ONLY for OPTIONS request.
If you return it for POST request then browser cancel the request (at least for chrome)

The following PHP code works for me

```
// Allow CORS
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
}   
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
}
```

I found similar questions with some misleading response:

- Server thread says that this is 2 years bug of chrome: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does not match with localhost. It's wrong: I can use CORS to my local server with Post normally
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does accept wildcards. It's also wrong, wildcard works for me (I tested only with Chrome)

This take me half day to figure out the issue.

Happy coding

Comment: Wildcard("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *") did not work for me, on Safari 7.0.4 .

Comment: I found that setting Access-Control-Allow-Headers works for POST in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 m.

Comment: This doesn't seem right..... The spec doesn't allow `*` on `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` even for `OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 2):

I got tripped up because what I actually wanted was a slightly different header.

- `access-control-ALLOW-headers` works for pre-flight request only. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)
- `access-control-EXPOSE-headers` works for the request itself, meaning Javascript can read the headers declared here. This is what I needed. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

I know this tangentially related, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from monsur,

> The Access-Control-Allow-Headers header does not allow wildcards. It
> must be an exact match:
> http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header.

So here is my php solution.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' . 
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS']);
}
```

Comment: Actually, why not simply `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS']);`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

here's the incantation for nginx, inside a

```
location / {
    # Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    }

}
```