# CORS, IIS7 and PHP - Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, php, iis-7, xmlhttprequest, cors

i'm trying to allow another host (a local host, like `javascript.dev`) to make a xhr to this host, it is an IIS7 and if i `curl -I` it, this is the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 12:09:33 GMT
```

this is the headers for `curl -v -X OPTIONS`:

```
* About to connect() to www2.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 200.98.xxx.100...
* Connected to www2.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br (200.98.xxx.100) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS /jobs/xxxxxxx/user/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: www2.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
* Server Microsoft-IIS/7.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 13:01:25 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

i used php to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but when i do the xhr, with or without jquery, this is the error i'm getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www2.xxxxxxxx.com.br/jobs/xxxxxx/user/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://javascript.dev' is therefore not allowed access.
```

to document, additional steps i made to solve:

i added code in the answer above to my web.config and get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/eminhasaude/user. 
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

because `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` don't accept wildcards `*`. to solve:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
```

Comment: So when you send `OPTIONS /jobs/xxxxxx/user/` it returns those headers as well? Presumably it does the the same for a `POST` to that address? What appears in the network tab of your browser's debug tools?

Comment: i added the headers for OPTIONS

Comment: I think that might be your problem - browsers perform an OPTIONS request before they perform the actual operation. Your OPTIONS does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: ok, really think this is the problem, but i can handle the response to OPTIONS request with my php application? and if can't, how i can do this in IIS7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based upon comments it looks like you're missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when an OPTIONS request is submitted. According to [this](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/) article it should be a simple case of adding the following code to your PHP page...

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

If that still doesn't work then you should check the IIS handler mapping for PHP (see [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php)) and make sure that OPTIONS is an allowed verb. Hopefully that does the job!

[This](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/) article also indicates that you could skip modifying the PHP at all and simply add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Be aware that this will open up the entire site rather than just one page...

Comment: ok, added this to web config, now the headers on OPTIONS request is:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS`

but im still receiving errors, now this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/eminhasaude/user. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. `

Comment: Looks like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` doesn't accept wildcards...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored. Try adding just Content-Type instead of the *

Comment: yeah i solved this as follow: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />`

Comment: Removing headers from php controller and making the above said changes in the web.config helped me. Thanks a ton.