# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to prepare a `Delete` request in `AngularJS` to a `nodeJS` local server:

```
this.deleteMusician = function(id) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/musicians/' + id,
            method: "DELETE",
            data: {}
            //processData: false,
            //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

And my `nodeJS` route looks like this:

```
app.delete('/musicians/:id', musicians.delete);
```

The same request via PostMan works, but on Google Chrome i get:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/musicians/5628eacaa972a6c5154e4162 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/musicians/5628eacaa972a6c5154e4162. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

CORS is enabled:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
};
```

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

Comment: Depending upon the middleware used you need to enable CORS on the server infrastructure as this seems to be a cross domain request.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure your node server to expect options method too.Check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497413/angular-http-delete-cors-error-preflight-request)

so:

```
app.options('/musicians/:id', optionsCB);
```

and:

```
exports.optionsCB = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type');

  next();
}
```