# I can't use ajax call api but postman call is ok

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I can't use ajax call API but postman call API is ok. I develop web API on .net core 2.2 and develop asp.net core MVC. Then I use ajax call to API url "https://localhost:44349" An error occurred in Figure 1.

API: EmployeeController

```
[HttpPost("CheckAuth")]
public IActionResult checkAuth(EmployeeLoginRequest req)
    {
        // logic
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeLoginResponse));
    }
```

API: Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(
                options => options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44320").AllowAnyMethod()
            );
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

WEB App: Index.cshtml

```
var data = {
                "username": $.trim($("#inputUsername").val()),
                "password": $.trim($("#inputPassword").val())
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:44349/Employee/CheckAuth",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

How do I fix it?

**Remark**
API Url: https://localhost:44349
Web Url: https://localhost:44320

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS to resolve this issue, 
Please follow below steps: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core-api-application/

If you already enabled it, then please check below url and try those steps.
[Missing token 'access-control-allow-headers' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332882/missing-token-access-control-allow-headers-in-cors-header-access-control-allo/32349817)

Comment: Have you noticed OP did enable CORS on the .Net Core API (not web api 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
app.UseCors(
    options => options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44349").AllowAnyMethod()
);
```