# CORS issue in node.js failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, cross-domain

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

I use postman everything work fine but I got CORS issue when testing my ionic app which it runs at http://localhost:8100. I googled and manage to find above set header solution but now I'm getting this error :

```
Request header field owner is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Any thought?

Comment: "[The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header does not allow wildcards.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored)"

Comment: @JonathanLonowski so which part should i change?

Comment: Besides ["simple" headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header), you'll have to list out exactly which headers should be permitted – e.g., `'Owner,X-Requested-With'` in place of the `'*'`.

Comment: You might also consider the [`cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the cors middleware.

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```