# Keycloak CORS issue associated with login redirect

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, keycloak

Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46220566/820657) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35953286/820657) have not helped me resolve the problem.

I am using Keycloak 4.4.0 to secure my REST service, which is implemented using Spring Boot and I am using React for the front end.

I get a CORS error when the front end (running on `localhost:3000`) makes an API call to `localhost:8080/login` and is redirected to the Keycloak login page.

The error is:

> localhost/:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/login: Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/login' to 'http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/hbs/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=hbs&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&state=ab5034a9-4baa-4be3-9ec1-feefbe5f9c0b&login=true&scope=openid' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I have added a single value of `'*'` to the `Web Origins` config section in the Keycloak client.

I have annotated my REST controller as follows:

```java
@RestController
class MyController
{
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo(Principal principal)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Foo("blah"));
    }
}
```

I have enabled Keycloak and CORS in the application properties:

```java
keycloak.cors = true
keycloak.enabled = true
```

If I disable Keycloak and CORS, problem goes away.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46222250/820657), I suspect the issue is to do with the Keycloak server not responding with any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers despite `Web Origins` being correctly configured in the Keycloak admin portal. But I'm not completely sure how to confirm this.

Comment: You need to ensure that both the port 8080 and 9080 servers are configured to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. And for the port 8080 server, ensure that it’s configured to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to 3xx responses — not just 2xx responses.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Please can you elaborate on how I do that.

Comment: @ksl did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @tryingToLearn No.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine the following json below is your Keycloak configuration:

```
{
  "realm" : "cors",
  "resource" : "cors-database-service",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost-auth:8080/auth",
  "bearer-only" : true,
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "enable-cors": true
}
```

Try adding the **last line** to your configuration file.
Let me know if it worked for you!

OBS: I'm facing the same issue, but I'm using Wildfly/JBOSS adapters and making this configuration inside the application server.

@EDIT:
This worked fine for me.

Try changing the "Access Type" to `bearer-only` inside your REST Client on Keycloak.

Also, don't forget to add the parameter {"{"Authorization" : "bearer " + $TOKEN} when sending HTTP requests from your client to your RESTful API.

Answer (score -1):

For those encountering this error with spring. Just add this class to your project to allow cors:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    String[] origins = new String[] { "http://localhost:8081"};
    
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("TEST TEST");
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*");
//              .allowedOrigins(origins);
    }
}
```

The asterisk allows all origins, which may not be secure for productive systems. A string array can be used to specify more than one origin.