# CORS: Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, php, cors, vue.js, lumen

Im building an app using vuejs and lumen for the api,

my vuejs app is throwing an error when trying to authenticate

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.dev/auth/login. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I have some middleware to handle cors

```
class cors {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
     protected $settings = [
      'maxAge'            => 0,
      'origin'            => '*',
      'allowMethods'      => '*',
      'exposeHeaders'     => '*',
      'allowedHeaders'    => '*'
     ];

public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request, Closure $next)
{
   //handle preflight request
    if ('OPTIONS' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $response =  new \Illuminate\Http\Response('',"204");
        $this->setOrigin($request, $response);
        $this->setAllowHeaders($request,$response);
        return $response;
    }
}

/**
 * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 */
protected function setOrigin(ServerRequestInterface $request,$response)
{
    $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
    if (is_callable($origin)) {
        $origin = call_user_func($origin,$response->withAddedHeader('Origin',$origin));
    }
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
}

/**
 * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 */
protected function setAllowHeaders(ServerRequestInterface $request,$response)
{
    if (isset($this->settings['allowedHeaders'])) {
        $allowedHeaders = $this->settings['allowedHeaders'];
        if (is_array($allowedHeaders)) {
            $allowedHeaders = implode(", ", $allowedHeaders);
        }
    }
    else { 
        $allowedHeaders = $request->hasHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    }

    if (isset($allowedHeaders)) {
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowedHeaders);
    }
}
}
```

In chrome my response headers show

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 10 Oct 2016 16:10:52 GMT
Server:Caddy
Status:204 No Content
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.10
```

If i've set a wild card Access-Control-Allow-Headers why is it not accepting the header?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored), wildcards for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is relatively recent (May 2016) so it's probably not widely adopted by most browsers.

You should probably define exactly what headers you want to allow in the preflight request.

Comment: im using the latest chrome browser and looking at other cors implementations they all seem to use wildcards

Comment: I believe the error message you're seeing is _coming from the browser_ so it's a safe bet the browser probably doesn't support it.  Why not change the wildcard to `Content-Type` and see what happens?

Comment: if I change my settings array allowed headers to          

 'allowedHeaders'    => 'Content-Type,Authorization,Origin',

my error message turns back to 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.dev//auth/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Which seems a step back

Comment: So your OPTIONS request is returning both `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and you're getting the message about a missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?