# Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (CORS )

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mautic

I have a main domain and a subdomain (**Mautic Is Installed**), unfortunately, I have a cross-origin HTTP request problem if mautic is setup within a subdomain. When I load the example.com I get the following errors in Safari Console:

```
Failed to load resource: Origin https://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://subdomain.example.com/mtc.
Origin https://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Which make sense for security reason.

So, I add header set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com` to https://subdomain.example.com `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. Thanks to this article about [CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). But, now I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: Credentials flag is true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not "true".
MLHttpRequest cannot load https://subdomain.example.com/mtc. Credentials flag is true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not "true".
```

Then, I add `header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. But I still get an error:

```
Failed to load resource: Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://subdomain.example.com/mtc. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

And, this is where I'm stuck, Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly the same, bit this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution to this issue. What you need to do is set the **Origin, Headers, and Credentials**. I miss the "headers" section which I didn't specify in my `httpd.conf`. Here is the complete configuration:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

Comment: didnt work `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'true, true'  which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'`