# {"isTrusted":true} exception in core.umd.js

Tags: angular, firefox

I'm using Angular 2 and everything is working great in Chrome, but
I started getting the following error in Firefox:

> EXCEPTION: 0 -  {"isTrusted":true} in   core.umd.js

I have no idea what is causing this or where it is coming from, so I don't even know where to begin with debugging it. I did some Googling, but couldn't find anything useful. Here is an image of what I'm seeing in the console:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what this means?

Comment: Does this happen in an environment with cross origin requests?

Comment: Yes it does. I used to have CORs issues, but got them resolved (or at least I thought I did). Chrome works great and I'm 99.9% sure Firefox was working before even with cross origin requests. Not sure what changed.

Answer (score 6):

I remember I had that issue once, too, and I *believe* I tracked it down to the following.

`{"isTrusted":true}` was the body of a request that was printed by my ErrorHandler that caught failed requests. The cause for the failed request was a CORS issue. I had a wildcard set for allowed origins in my Tomcat's web.xml for testing purposes:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It turned out that Firefox, at least in that particular version I used, didn't like wildcards and, thus, resulted in a failed request although the preflight had succeeded. After setting the origin to a qualified name, everything worked fine. And just like you, I never had those issues in Chrome.

[See this SO question, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored)

Hope that helps to track down your issue.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll accept this once I have time to look into that (assuming it fixes the problem).