# Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost Safari

Tags: ios, safari, xmlhttprequest

Making XMLHttpRequests in iOS WKWebView when idle (in background) and locking screen causes the request to error out and we get this in the safari console log:

Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost

Does anyone know why Safari closes the connection? Or is it the server closing the connection?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Contacted Apple support, this is actually done by design. WKWebView has been "optimized" to not make network connections while screen is locked.

Comment: Would you please provide more details about this? I'm struggling with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using Angular and also getting this error:

```
0 -  {"isTrusted":true}
```

I have been getting the error you are getting along with this one.

In any sense I found this answer helpful because it's probably a CORS issue:

[{"isTrusted":true} exception in core.umd.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968860/istrustedtrue-exception-in-core-umd-js)

Hope that at least points you in the right direction.