# How to prevent cancelling pending request in mobile safari/ios chrome when the app is put to background?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, chrome-ios

iPhone X, iOS 12.1.2

Situation:

1. I'm making a request which does a long time to finish
2. In the meantime i'm switching to other app
3. When I put Safari back in the foreground it says that the connection was lost

When I'm not switching it to the background there is no such issue. It's like that on Chrome and Safari, but only on iOS. Chrome on Android works fine.

Comment: Not sure but you can try web worker to send request and from worker send data to main tread, web workers sometimes don't have limitations of main thread when tab is not in focus.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505618/failed-to-load-resource-the-network-connection-was-lost-safari, this guy says it's by design. In that case, I'd find a way to get around this using synchronic requests. I think it's probably too complicated for most issues, but I can't come up with a better solution.