# How can I add a glossiness / specular texture to a GLTF model?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, textures, gltf

**QUESTION:**

I have a specular/glossiness texture image for a model which is not yet being used by the GLTF model.

How can I use/add the texture to my model so that it is reflective/glossy where it should be ?

I don't know what to change inside the .gltf file to make use of the texture.

**EDIT:** Added more lines of the GLTF to get a better picture of the situation.

---

**GLTF JSON:**

```
"images": [
    {
        "name": "...",
        "uri": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "uri": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "uri": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "uri": "..."
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "uri": "..."
    }
],
"samplers": [
    {}
],
"textures": [
    {
        "name": "T_N",
        "sampler": 0,
        "source": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Map #9",
        "sampler": 0,
        "source": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "T_D",
        "sampler": 0,
        "source": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Map #6",
        "sampler": 0,
        "source": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Specular",
        "sampler": 0,
        "source": 4
    }
],

"materials": [
    {
        "name": "Head",
        "alphaMode": "OPAQUE",
        "extras": {
            "fromFBX": {
                "shadingModel": "<unknown>",
                "isTruePBR": false
            }
        },
        "normalTexture": {
            "index": 0,
            "texCoord": 0
        },
        "emissiveTexture": {
            "index": 1,
            "texCoord": 0
        },
        "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
            "baseColorTexture": {
                "index": 2,
                "texCoord": 0
            },
            "baseColorFactor": [
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ],
            "metallicFactor": 0.800000002980232,
            "roughnessFactor": 0.600000011920929
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Body",
        "alphaMode": "BLEND",
        "extras": {
            "fromFBX": {
                "shadingModel": "<unknown>",
                "isTruePBR": true
            }
        },
        "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
            "baseColorTexture": {
                "index": 3,
                "texCoord": 0
            },
            "baseColorFactor": [
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ],
            "metallicFactor": 0.80000002980232,
            "roughnessFactor": 0.600000011920929
        },
        "extensions": {
            "KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness": {
                "specularGlossinessTexture": {
                    "index": 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"meshes": [
    {
        "name": "Head",
        "primitives": [
            {
                "material": 0,
                "mode": 4,
                "attributes": {
                    "COLOR_0": 3,
                    "NORMAL": 2,
                    "POSITION": 1,
                    "TEXCOORD_0": 4
                },
                "indices": 0,
                "extensions": {
                    "KHR_draco_mesh_compression": {
                        "bufferView": 0,
                        "attributes": {
                            "COLOR_0": 2,
                            "NORMAL": 1,
                            "POSITION": 0,
                            "TEXCOORD_0": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Body",
        "primitives": [
            {
                "material": 1,
                "mode": 4,
                "attributes": {
                    "COLOR_0": 8,
                    "NORMAL": 7,
                    "POSITION": 6,
                    "TEXCOORD_0": 9
                },
                "indices": 5,
                "extensions": {
                    "KHR_draco_mesh_compression": {
                        "bufferView": 1,
                        "attributes": {
                            "COLOR_0": 2,
                            "NORMAL": 1,
                            "POSITION": 0,
                            "TEXCOORD_0": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

---

**ERROR:**

Here is the error I am currenlty getting with the above modified GLTF when trying to load the model:

```
{"message":"Cannot read property 'getMaterialType' of undefined","name":"TypeError"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good examples in the glTF-Sample-Models repository. Here is the same model using two different PBR workflows:

- [spec/gloss PBR material](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/Corset/glTF-pbrSpecularGlossiness/Corset.gltf#L121-L147)
- [metal/rough PBR material](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/Corset/glTF/Corset.gltf#L109-L125)

Your example JSON above is using metal/rough, so you'll have to "convert" it to spec/gloss by replacing the metallic and roughness factors with equivalent spec/gloss properties.

I'd suggest taking a look at the specification for more info:

- [glTF specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md)
- [spec/gloss extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness/README.md)

You may also find it easier to do this in a tool like Substance Painter or Blender, which can import and export glTF.

Comment: I bet the following error: `{"message":"Cannot read property 'getMaterialType' of undefined","name":"TypeError"}` after adding the fields from :https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/Corset/glTF-pbrSpecularGlossiness/Corset.gltf#L121-L147

Comment: Updated my current GLTF file in the question with the changes and more lines.

Comment: Would you have any idea what might be causing the error ?

Comment: I think you’ll need to post the entire glTF file using Google Drive or Dropbox or something. There are glTF “validation” tools that can also help.

Comment: I validated the file, now I am getting the exact same error as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839039/getting-an-istrustedtrue-error-when-using-gltfloader  I have no idea what might be causing this...

Comment: How is this supposed to be used if the spec gloss model specifies rough/metal parameters?

Comment: Do you mean what will the user see if the model has both spec/gloss and metal/rough parameters? See [spec/gloss best practices](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness/README.md#best-practices), but tl;dr the engine can choose one of the two.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy  We need separate textures for base, rough, metallic in Blender? It kinda adds up the file size. Is there a way to show glossiness with one texture?

Comment: If you're using Blender, use Principled BSDF materials and base color, rough, and metal textures. The metal and rough textures will be merged automatically. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/io_gltf2.html