# OPTIONS request works in chrome fails in safari

Tags: rest, safari, cors, access-control

I'm at the end of my rope on this one...   i'm running into a cors issue in safari related to a content-type header.  I own the backend and have confirmed it is returning "*" for Access-Control-Allow-Headers.  Anyone have any ideas what this could be?

[chrome request/response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOIRp.png)

[safari request/response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyZcf.png)

Comment: Do you have the Safari response headers - they're not in that screenshot.

Comment: i don't get any response headers in safari

Comment: This worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was safari & ie don't honor * for this header so:
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*"` is rejected.
  After explicitly adding 'accept' and 'content-type' this was resolved: 
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*, accept, content-type"`